# Force chrome mobile browser to view mobile websites

Tags: browser, chrome-for-android

I am using chrome browser on a 5.5-inch smartphone. I notice that for phones with big screen, the website defaults to the desktop version. This goes the same for tablets. However, I will prefer to view the mobile website version on these devices. How can this be done?

Comment: I've got the Nexus 5  with a similar screen size and I haven't experienced this issue before. What sites are you experiencing these issues on? Also, you don't have `Request desktop site` enabled for those sites by any chance do you?

Comment: `Request desktop site` is disabled. Browsing general news websites like www.economist.com

Comment: [Here's what I see](http://i.imgur.com/B67vABR.png) on my 1080p Nexus 5. As far as I know, there's no special option to request the mobile site because any well-designed site should already be serving a mobile phone that version by default. Still, on particularly high-res devices you might still face some issues. What's your device model and resolution?

Comment: Using LG G4. Seems like yours is the mobile version. Wonder what went wrong with my phone.

Comment: @Huey Nexus 5 screen 5.5 inch? I thought all models of nexus 5 were 4.95 inches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think there is *no problem* with your phone. The problem is with the Website. Now a days websites are following '**Responsive web design**' means 'Websites' automatically rescale/resizes(looks bigger or smaller)  themselves in respect to **screen sizes** of the viewing device which  depends on the website developer. 
I checked "*www.economist.com*" website.It **only have desktop version** so your phone display that desktop version. 
 **You can't view mobile version because there is no Mobile version of the site .** Be happy :)

Comment: This doesn't address the core question, which is "*However, I will prefer to view the mobile website version on these devices. How can this be done?*".

Comment: **You can't view mobile version  because there is no Mobile version of the site**

Comment: ***E.g.: in Firefox, you can force a website with responsive design to show  mobile or desktop layout on Desktop. The same is true for its mobile app as well.*** All I'm saying is you've mentioned the cause, not the remedy.

Comment: If a website doesn't have a  mobile site, how can you view that?  Even '**Forcing the website to show  mobile site in Firefox**' is useless because that Website  _neither Responsive design nor have a mobile site_ .

Comment: A mobile version of a site offers you a layout different from the desktop. This is simply what responsive does too but with less complexity  of focusing on user-agent (UA) or providing a separate domain. In a broader sense, both gives you a layout. When you switch the UA to mobile in a desktop browser, you attempt to fool a typical website showing the browser as a mobile, so the site redirects you to the mobile version...continued...

Comment: .....Since this spoofing doesn't work on sites with responsive design, you use an another hack which involves spoofing the density of the screen. Given the density equivalent to what a mobile would have, you would have a mobile layout on a desktop. *It is immaterial to the question whether the site has a separate mobile version or not. The question simply asks for a remedy. That's it*.

Comment: This misses the point and doesn't answer the question.  The method that the page uses to display the different "versions" is irrelevant, whether it's css/js or server-side.  It's still a different interface.